# Using VectorPlot3D to plot the electric field of a 2 point charge system in Mathematica

Tags: plot, wolfram-mathematica

I am attempting to plot the electric field of a 2 point charge system consisting of 2 point charges q<sub>1</sub> with charge +1 at position (0,0,1) and q<sub>2</sub> with charge -1 at position (0,0-1).

Below is the code I have been using by following the example in the applications section of mathematica's documentation for VectorPlot3D.

Everything seems to be working except for the plotting the electric field and I am not sure why.

Please note that my electric potential uses a 0.01 offset to prevent singularity at r=0.

Defining the electrostatic potential

```
electroStaticPotential[q_, p_, r_] := 
 Sum[q[[i]]/Norm[(r + 0.01) - p[[i]]], {i, Length[q]}]
```

Displaying Electrostatic potential with symbols

```
electroStaticPotential[{Subscript[q, 1], Subscript[q, 2]}, {{Subscript[x, 1], Subscript[y, 1], Subscript[z, 1]}, {Subscript[x, 2], Subscript[y, 2], Subscript[z, 2]}}, {x, y, z}] // TraditionalForm
```

Displaying Electrostatic potential with values

```
electroStaticPotential[{1, -1}, {{0, 0, 1}, {0, 0, -1}}, {x, y, z}] // TraditionalForm
```

defining the electric field

```
electricField[{q1_, q2_}, {{x1_, y1_, z1_}, {x2_, y2_, z2_}}] = -D[electroStaticPotential[{q1, q2}, {{x1, y1, z1}, {x2, y2, z2}}, {x, y, z}], {{x, y, z}}] /. Abs'[x_] :> x/Sqrt[x^2];
```

Here I generate the ContourPlot of my potential.

```
c = ContourPlot3D[Evaluate[electroStaticPotential[{1, -1}, {{0, 0, 1}, {0,0, -1}}, {x, y, z}]], {x, -6, 6}, {y, 0, 4}, {z, -4, 4}, Contours -> {-0.75, -0.25, -0.1, 0, 0.1, 0.25, 0.75}, ContourStyle -> Table[Hue[i/7, 1, 1, 0.5], {i, 0, 6}], Mesh -> None]
```

[image: <img src="http://i.imgur.com/QzrQkTi.pn" alt="ContourPlot" height="42" width="42">]

Generating the vectorplot of the electric field. (Not working)

```
v = VectorPlot3D[Evaluate[electricField[{1, -1}, {{0, 0, 1}, {0, 0, -1}}]], {x, -6, 6}, {y, 0, 4}, {z, -4, 4}, VectorStyle -> "Arrow3D", VectorPoints -> 5, VectorScale -> {.3, Scaled[0.3]}]
```

[image]

Combine the contour and vector plot

```
Show[c, v]
```

[image]

Comment: it works for me. The plot is very sparse because you have `VectorPoints` so small, try leaving that automatic.

Comment: Odd, even leaving VectorPoints to be automatically assigned doesn't produce anything visible on my plot.

Comment: could be a version issue. You might want to ask on mathematica.stackexchange.com

Comment: Okay, I'll ask there. I'm on Mathematica 11 if that makes any difference